# Question about proof structuring.

Tags: general-topology

Let $d$ and $d_1$ be metrics on $X$ and $Y$ and $T$ and $T_1$ be induced topologies on $X$ and $Y$, respectively.  $f:(X,T) \to (Y,T_1)$ is continuous iff for each $x_0$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that $x$ is an element of $X$ and $d(x, x_0) < \delta$ implies $d_1(f(x), f(x_0)) < \epsilon$.

For proving this in the forward direction, what exactly am I allowed to assume here?  I know I can say: Let $f$ be continuous, $x_0$ be an arbitrary element of $X$, and $\epsilon > 0$.  Can I also assume that $x$ is an element of $X$ and $d(x, x_0) < \delta$ and then try to show that $d_1(f(x), f(x_0)) < \epsilon$?

(A link to help with formatting mathematical symbols in LaTeX would be helpful)

Comment: There’s a basic guide and tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What's your definition of continuous?  It is often taught this was the definition of continuous and thus there would be nothing to prove.

Comment: In order to answer your question, we’ll need to know how you’ve defined continuity, so that we know exactly what you’re assuming when you assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @fleablood: Continuity of $f$ may have been defined globally, as it often is in a general topological setting: $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: Any other definition would be satisfactory, I'm just trying to understand how much I can assume for the B part of the structure of the proof A =>( B => C).

Comment: @Oliver: It really will depend on the definition of continuity that you’re using. The structure of the statement is more complicated than $A\to(B\to C)$: it’s $$A\to \forall x_0,\epsilon\,\exists\delta\,\forall x\,\big(\varphi(x,x_0,\delta)\to\varphi(f(x),f(x_0),\epsilon)\big)\;.$$ The quantifiers affect what you can do and what you must do.

Comment: I would be using the definition you used, or, $$x_n -> x => f(x_n) -> f(x).$$

Comment: I’ll show you what happens with both. Give me a few minutes to write it up.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Good point.  Then the proof is a matter of showing that that if if U is open in Y using the metric definition of open that there is a epsilon so a delta ball of x_o is in U then this statement claims there is an delta so a delta ball is in f_inv(U) so f_inv(U) is open by the metric definition iff f is cont by topological def.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s assume first that $f$ is continuous in the sense that $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $Y$. We want to show that for each $x_0\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $d_1\big(f(x),f(x_0)\big)<\epsilon$ whenever $d(x,x_0)<\delta$. Thus, we let $x_0$ be an arbitrary point of $X$ and $\epsilon$ an arbitrary positive real number. Let $U=B\big(f(x_0),\epsilon\big)$, and let $V=f^{-1}[U]$; $U$ is open in $Y$, so $V$ is open in $X$. Clearly $x_0\in V$, so there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B(x_0,\delta)\subseteq V$, and it’s easy now to verify that this $\delta$ has the desired property.

It’s the *for each* in *for each* $x_0\in X$ *and* $\epsilon>0$ that tells me that I should begin with arbitrary instances of each. Everything after that, though, depended on the definition of continuity that I was using, since it was the only tool available to give me objects to work with to produce the desired $\delta$.

Now let’s assume instead that $f$ is sequentially continuous. Again we want to show that for each $x_0\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $d_1\big(f(x),f(x_0)\big)<\epsilon$ whenever $d(x,x_0)<\delta$, so again we would start a direct proof by letting $x_0$ be an arbitrary point of $X$ and $\epsilon$ an arbitrary positive real number. Unfortunately, sequential continuity doesn’t really give us much to work with. We know that for each sequence $\sigma=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ that converges to $x_0$ there is some $m_{\sigma,\epsilon}\in\Bbb N$ such that $d_1\big(f(y_n),f(x_0)\big)<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_{\sigma,\epsilon}$, but that $m_{\sigma,\epsilon}$ doesn’t really help: it doesn’t directly yield any distance $\delta$ in $X$, and in any case it depends on which sequence converging to $x_0$ we’re using at the moment.

I don’t see a direct proof for this implication. I would instead prove the contrapositive: if there are an $x_0\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that no matter what $\delta>0$ we try, there is a point $y_\delta\in X$ such that $d(y_\delta,x_0)<\delta$ and $d_1\big(f(y_\delta),f(x_0)\big)\ge\epsilon$, then $f$ is *not* sequentially continuous at $x_0$. It’s not hard to verify that in this case the sequence $\langle y_{1/n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $x_0$, but its image under $f$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$, because  $d_1\big(f(y_{1/n}),f(x_0)\big)\ge\epsilon$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: Thank you, the "for each" arbitrary instances was exactly the question that I was asking.  So, in general,  as long as an existential quantifier is used at some point, anything after it would have to be constructed or proven.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @Oliver: You’re welcome. Yes, once you have to show that something exists, you need sufficient tools to do so; in the first version I had them, and in the second I didn’t, so I had to try something completely different.